# how to get all the collections under a database in mongodb using python dynamically?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
Client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
dbs = Client.database_names()
for val in range(len(dbs)):
    print "%s : %s"%(val,dbs[val])
database = input(" Select the Database ")
ex = dbs[database]

print ex
cols = Client.ex.collection_names()
print cols
for c in cols:
    print c
```

Here is my code .. if i use Client.m101.collection_names() i can get all collections under database.
Note : m101 is my database. But i want to take database from user and want to read collections under the database entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

You can access databases using dictionary-style access on the **[`MongoClient`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient)** connection instance, which removes Python-specific naming restrictions, as in the following:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def get_collection_names(dbname):
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client[dbname]
    return db.collection_names()

def main():
    database = input(" Select the Database ")
    cols = get_collection_names(database)
    for c in cols:
        print c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```